# Flutter | Xcode | "could not build the precompiled application for the device"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, certificate

If you are seeing this error when building a Flutter app for a physical iOS device, here is the solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had this error when building for a physical iOS device in Flutter or in the Runner.xcworkspace project. I spent probably 8-9 hours trying to remedy this error, following countless tutorials and answers on other StackOverflow questions. NOTHING worked.

Today, I coincidentally found the solution (in my case) and it may be the one for you if you're experiencing this error since Apple changed their `Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate`.

- Open `Keychain Access`, select `login` on the left pane, select `Certificates` at the top, search `apple`, delete all:
- Apple Distribution certificates
- Apple Development certificates
- Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificates
- **(DO NOT DELETE your `Apple Push Services` certificates**
- [image: Like this]
- Click [this](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer) to download the new `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` certificate.
- Click it to add it to your Keychain.
- In `Keychain Access`, at the top, go to `Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority`
- [image: Keychain Access Menu]
- Type in your email (most likely your Apple ID).
- Select `Save to Disk` and choose your `Downloads` folder.
- Go to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com).
- Click `Account`, sign in with your Apple ID / Developer Account.
- Click `Certificates, IDs & Profiles`.
- Again, revoke any `Development`/`Distribution` certificates.
- **Click the plus icon, select `Apple Development`**
- **Upload the signing request you just made.**
- **Download the certificate.**
- **Click the certificate to add it to your Keychain.**
- Repeat the bold steps for the `Apple Distribution` option.
- Open your Xcode workspace.
- Click your project, click your Target, click `Signing & Capabilities`
- If you see a red error below your Apple ID, click the button to resolve it.

You should then be good to go!
I hope this helped you.